# jQuery-ui-autocomplete from text source

Tags: java, jquery, firebug, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I try to use **autocomplete jquery-ui** script, but from the documentation it's explain that the remote source must return a **json data**, it's not talking about **plain text** response,
and I develop my application in **jsp/servlet** and I don't know how to create json data.

So I've discover an other jquery autocomplete plugin --> [autocomplete feature with java](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery.html)

This tutorial and the script work great but the script has not same options that I need.
I try to keep the same getdata.jsp and servlet pages for adapt to jquery-ui-autocomplete just changing the link of script, and **firebug** say me the **correct response** to the request but that's **not displayed**!

[ScreenShot of firebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZCwC.png)

JavaScript call:

```
<script>
$(function() {

$( "#responsable" ).autocomplete({
    source: "getdata.jsp",
    minLength: 2
});
});
</script>
```

here is the getdata.jsp file:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="fr.myldap.model.*"%>
<%
PersonneDB db = new PersonneDB();
String query = request.getParameter("term");

List<Personne> personnes = db.getData(query);

Iterator<Personne> iterator = personnes.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    String personne = (String)iterator.next().getNomComplet();
    out.println(personne);
}

%>
```

and here is the PersonneDB class wich return the person list

```
package fr.myldap.model;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PersonneDB {
private LDAPInterneDao piDao;
private LDAPExterneDao peDao;

public PersonneDB() {
    ContextVar var= new ContextVar();
    piDao = var.getPiDao();
    peDao = var.getPeDao();
}

public List<Personne> getData(String query) {
    List<Personne> matched = new ArrayList<Personne>(piDao.findByName(query));
    matched.addAll(peDao.findByName(query));

    return matched;
}
}
```

I hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all download the json library for java from [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/json-lib/json-lib-2.4/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar/download) location.

Now to return the JSON data you need to follow its own format, something like :

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": 10021
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        "212 732-1234",
        "646 123-4567"
    ]
}
```

As you can see above, json data can have key:value pair, object can be stored inside `{ }`, array can be store in `[ ]` and so on.

Now to convert your response into JSON object you need to import following statement in your jsp file :

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
```

(it may change depend on the lib that you are downloading, you can explore javadoc for more detail)

Now look at to the following code, to create a json object and return it :

```
    JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
    object.put("name","Amit Kumar");
    object.put("employeeList",employeeList);
....
....
    System.out.println("json object = "+object);
    return object;
```

It will automatically convert the key:value pair into correct JSON object...

**UPDATE :**

Required Libraries :

```
commons-lang 2.3
commons-beanutils 1.7.0
commons-collections 3.2
commons-logging 1.1
ezmorph 1.0.4.jar
json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar
```

You can download all from [here](http://csm2kh.googlepages.com/JSON.zip) :

To convert arraylist to json, use following sample code :

```
List mybeanList = new ArrayList();
mybeanList.add(myBean1);
mybeanList.add(myBean2);

JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject(mybeanList);
System.out.println("==== : "+jsonArray);

Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("beanlist", jsonArray);

JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(map);
return jsonObject;
```

Comment: thank you, i have the json library and i've understand your explication but i have to return much than one person to autocomplete, I have an ArrayList of persons i need and i want to return a JSON data of this list of objects!

Comment: Also returning the json object is not the end, you need to parse the returned JSON object at client side... So explore that portion too...

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.json.JsonConfig 

on the JSONArray.fromObject(list);

Comment: Make sure that you have all the required jar files in your classpath.... And see my corrected answer...

Comment: My answer includes up to date versions of the libraries and a working example!

Answer (score 2):

Learn how to create JSON. It's replacing XML as the information interchange medium.

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/json/json-jsp-example.shtml

Comment: ok but which syntax and type of JSON data must I use? (Array, Object, String)

ex: 

JSON{
    personne1{
        attr1{}
        attr2{}
        ...
    }
    personne2{
        attr1{}
        attr2{}
    }
}???

Comment: and i don't know how to return a json object to a query

Comment: That is an overly broad statement. XML definitely has its place still and will not be obsolete for a long time. However, in this example I agree that JSON is the most lightweight a simple solution. +1 for a good link as well

Answer (score 2):

You should start with [json.org](http://json.org/) and decide if you want to return a JSON array or object first.

The [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) is a very flexible plugin and I think the simplest solution would be to return JSON from your JSP in order to utilise the plugin.

I have found the [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) very easy to get running. You will need to download that and the dependencies ([commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/download_collections.cgi), [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi), [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi), [ezmorph](http://ezmorph.sourceforge.net/), [commons-beantils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/download_beanutils.cgi)) and add them to your `WEB-INF\lib` directory.

You could then use something as simple as a [JSONArray](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html):

```
<%@page import="java.util.*, net.sf.json.*"%>
<%
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    data.add("John");
    data.add("Paul");
    data.add("George");
    data.add("Ringo");
    JSONArray json = JSONArray.fromObject(data);
    out.println(json);
%>
```

which returns `["John","Paul","George","Ringo"]`

The jQuery UI autocomplete will also function with a [JSONObject](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html) if you want to return a `<key, value>` pair instead.

For completeness, my `WEB-INF\lib` directory contains the following:

```
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
ezmorph-1.0.6.jar
json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
```

**Edit:** Updated example JSP

```
<%@page import="java.util.*, net.sf.json.*"%>
<%!
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
%>
<%
    List<Person> data = new ArrayList<Person>();
    data.add(new Person("John"));
    data.add(new Person("Paul"));
    data.add(new Person("George"));
    data.add(new Person("Ringo"));

    JSONArray json = JSONArray.fromObject(data);
    out.println(json);
%>
```